# How to specify path in os.system() to execute a shell script in Flask

Tags: python, shell, flask

I am using Flask to execute a shell script and here is my actual code:

```
def execute(cmd, files):
    os.system(cmd)
    back =dict()
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            info = f.read()
            back[file] = info
    return back

@app.route('/executeScript', methods = ['POST'])
def executeScript():
    output = execute('./script.sh', ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'])

    return render_template('template.html', output=output)
```

But I want to put my script (script.sh) in a particular folder. For that I need to add the path in my code, but when add it, it doesn't work anymore. I've tried something like:

```
output = execute(['sh', 'path/to/myscript/script.sh'], ['path/to/myscript/file1.txt', 'path/to/myscript/file2.txt'])
```

But this is not working, the script is not executed at all.
Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: What if you supply the absolute path from root and start the path with a forward slash? E.g. `/home/username/scripts/shell_script.sh`

Comment: I've tried that too, and it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out!
In the script I was executing (script.sh) I was redirecting the output of some commands to text files.
I needed to add the path the absolute path in those text files like this:

```
some command > home/path/to/file.txt
```

this code is working fine though: `output = execute(['sh', 'path/to/myscript/script.sh'], ['path/to/myscript/file1.txt', 'path/to/myscript/file2.txt'])`

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2):

According to the description of [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) (emphasis mine):

> Execute the command **(a string)** in a subshell.

When you try to run

```
execute(['sh', 'path/to/myscript/script.sh'], ...)
```

...you end up passing a list to `os.system`. Try

```
execute('sh path/to/myscript/script.sh', ...)
```

Comment: Here is the error I get when I try that: path/to/myscript/script.sh: Permission denied

Comment: Then you are on the right track; the permission problem is unrelated, but also a problem.  But you really should try to migrate away from `os.system()` as outlined in another comment of mine.

Answer (score 1):

Also what you can use is "subprocess.Popen(path)", online documentation on subprocess module is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: This should be a lot clearer, but the basic message that `os.system()` is obsolete and that you should prefer `subprocess` instead is sanctioned even in the `os.system()` documentation.  Coincidentally, this will also make your current code easier to fix, though the details of how it's wrong are in another, unrelated answer

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you have the correct path for your file?  Triple check as this is often the problem ;o

I would have a variable like this:

```
script_dir = 'path/to/myscript'
```

Then have

```
output = execute(['sh', os.path.join(script_dir, 'script.sh')], [os.path.join(script_dir, 'file1.txt'), os.path.join(script_dir, 'file2.txt'])
```

as this will make it less likely that you make typos.    You might even want to go further and have:

```
script = os.path.join(script_dir, 'script.sh')
file_1 = os.path.join(script_dir, 'file1.txt')
```

etc.
then:

```
output = execute(['sh', script], [file_1, file_2])
```

This will make it easier to read and to edit, should your paths ever change.

hope this solves the problem!

Comment: I now see the other answer, doh!  Should have read the docs for os.system, always the way

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this be better? It uses the subprocess module rather than the deprecated os.system()

```
import subprocess

def execute(cmd, files):
    subp_ret = ""
    cmd_list = [cmd]
    cmd_list.extend(files)
    try:
        subp_ret = subprocess.check_output(cmd_list)
        """ at this point you have the output of the command in subp_ret in case you need it """
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to run subprocess. Details: " + str(e))
    back =dict()
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            info = f.read()
            back[file] = info
    return back

@app.route('/executeScript', methods = ['POST'])
def executeScript():
    output = execute('./script.sh', ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'])
    return render_template('template.html', output=output)
```